# How to select a boundary condition in Ansys

Tags: ansys-workbench

In Ansys, let’s say I wanted one end of a beam for example to be fixed (so sort of like clamped in reality),

How would I apply this boundary condition to that end?

Assuming I have a model already made

Comment: Does Ansys help have an entry fro Boundary Conditions?

Comment: They do, I just am not sure where to go after pressing it? I thought I should select the side but then how do I put the condition on?

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial video on how to model a simple beam. Pay attention from 5:04 and on. https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=specify+beam+end+support+in+ansys&view=detail&mid=4AD54C49E927B66A12DA4AD54C49E927B66A12DA&FORM=VIRE